# Nice way to compare 3 array lengths in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have 3 arrays. I have to check whether those arrays have the same length. Is there a clever and nice way to compare it?

Comment: `a.Length == b.Lenght && b.Length == c.Length` ?

Answer (score 10):

Why not

```
if (array1.Length == array2.Length && array1.Length == array3.Length)
{
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have `N` arrays you could do this:

```
var a1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var a2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var a3 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var arr = new[] { a1, a2, a3 }; // group them all in one array

// check if all arrays have the same length as the first
var test = arr.All(x => x.Length == a1.Length);
```

Comment: this is great for comparing lots of list and to also easily check if an array is `null` like `arr.All (x => x != null && x.Length == a1.Length)`

Answer (score 4):

`bool EqualLengths = Arr1.Length == Arr2.Length && Arr2.Length == Arr3.Length;`
Doubt that counts as clever and nice though, but don't think there's anything better!

Answer (score 4):

```
object[] a, b, c;
return (a.Length == b.Length && b.Length == c.Length);
```

Comment: objects do not have a Length property.

Comment: DOH, I see what you did there.

Answer (score 2):

more simple than `if (array1.Length == array2.Length && array1.Length == array3.Length)` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
bool success = false;

var arr1 = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
var arr2 = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
var arr3 = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };

if (arr1.Length == arr2.Length)
{
  if (arr2.Length == arr3.Length)
  {
     success = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
 if (array.Length == array1.Length &&  array1.Length== array2.Length)
{
 // do something
}
```

Comment: You can't concatenate 2 `==` operators. The result of the first == is a bool, then cannot be compared with an integer.

Comment: Doesn't work. You'll end up comparing `array1.Length == true` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: array.Length == array2.Length is of type boolean, and could never be compared to array3.Length, even if this were legal syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
// compares all arrays passed in for equal length.
// requires at least two arrays so that comparison can be made, 
// otherwise this operation would not matter
bool AreEqualLength(Array a1, Array a2, params Array[] arrs) {
  if (a1.Length != a2.Length) return false;
  foreach(var arr in arrs)
    if (arr.Length != a1.Length)
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        int[] a1, a2, a3;
        a1 = new int[3];
        a2 = new int[1];
        a3 = new int[1];

        bool equalLength = (a1.Length == (a2.Length & a3.Length));
```

Comment: I don't think doing a bitwise comparison is very readable. If I read the line, I'm not seeing easily what is actually happening.

Comment: a1.Length and a2.Length could be 2 and a3.Length could be 3 and this would give true. -1

Comment: @Martijn: The question ain't about readability but about clever way of comparing three values.